# SFMC Import Activity - Campaigns & Reports

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

Does anyone know when 'SFMC Import Activity - Campaigns & Reports' changed to 'SFMC Import Activity - Objects & Reports'?

I was hoping to use an Import Activity in SFMC to import Campaign Members from SFDC but that functionality doesn't appear any more. Has anyone else experienced the same?

I was under the impression that the Import Activity was the means to bring Contacts and Leads from SFDC into SFMC based on the Contact and Lead ID to enable a 'true' integration of records between the two different platforms? The Import Activity would land the SFDC Contacts and/or Leads in a Salesforce Data Extension. From here we'd be able to create IERs etc in SFDC?

Has anyone else encountered this issue and found workarounds?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't used that feature for quite some time because there are better options at hand now. If you only want to send straight emails without further data manipulation to report or campaign members you can now select both directly in the email send flow dialog without the need to import them beforehand. Campaigns and Campaign Members can also be used for Salesforce entry events if you use journey builder. Do you have needs that go beyond those two approaches?

Comment: Hi Stephan, Thanks for your comment. So I'm not going mad? It was once a feature of the Import Activity into a Salesforce Data Extension integration :) I recall using both Reprts and Campaigns via the Import Activity and they would land in a Salesforce Data Extension. This was necessary to ensure IERs etc were updated on the Contact and Lead - essentially ensuring recognition between both systems (SFMC + SFDC) via the Contact and Lead IDs.To clarify, we're now able to do this via Journey Builder? Cheers!

Comment: Yes, it was and you're not going mad. :D

Comment: if my answer helped please be so kind to mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for validating my sanity, Stephan :) I'll take a closer look at the JB alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

There are four new ways now you get tracking data to Salesforce CRM:

1. Emails sent in Journeys based on Salesforce Entry Events
2. Emails sent in Journeys based on data extensions where the Subscriber Relationship is based on a Salesforce Contact/Lead/Personcontact Id
3. Emails sent to data extensions in the Salesforce Data Extensions folder structure where the Subscriber Relationship is based on a Salesforce Contact/Lead/Personcontact Id
4. Emails sent to Salesforce reports or campaigns selected in the Email send flow or in Salesforce Send Emails definitions in Email Studio > Interactions